# nginx serving page code instead of page content

Tags: docker, nginx

I am setting up an instance of [the official nginx docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) to serve a static web page. The `Dockerfile` contains the following:

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./html /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

As for the configuration file:

```
http {
    server {
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index        index.htm;
    }
}

events {
    worker_connections        1024;
}
```

The image is compiling successfully, and is put up on port 8090:

```
docker run --name hello-world -d -p 8090:80 hello-world-nginx
```

When I access the port from a web browser, I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the mime types file to nginx config:

```
http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index        index.htm;
    }
}

events {
    worker_connections        1024;
}
```